# How to skip PDFing Hidden worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code below that PDFs everything in a range given, but it looks like it fails if there is a hidden tab between the two ranges given.
Is there a way to skip the hidden tab and PDF only visible?
Thank you.

```
Sub createPdf()

Dim SheetArr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim startSheet As Integer
Dim endSheet As Integer

startSheet = Sheets(InputBox("Sheet name?", "CreatePDF")).Index
endSheet = Sheets(InputBox("Sheet name?", "CreatePDF")).Index
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = InputBox("folderPath?", "CreatePDF")
Filename = InputBox("fileName?", "CreatePDF")
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Index >= startSheet And ws.Index <= endSheet Then ' <> "Sheet3" Then
    ReDim Preserve SheetArr(i)
    SheetArr(i) = ws.Name

    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print (ws.Name)

End If
Next

Sheets(SheetArr).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, 
Filename:=folderPath & Filename, _
openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

MsgBox "All done with pdf's"

End Sub
```

Comment: You load the hidden sheet into SheetArr, either dont do that, or delete it from the array for before printing

Comment: You may use a check: `If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then` and add only visible sheets to array. Or you may add it to your check in case you do need to add sheets regarding their index.

Comment: If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then did the trick thank you!